# Стилизовать опции

Tags: php, html, css

Подскажите как выровнять данные опции? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    <?php
// Время работы
$time = '10:00-17:00';
// Выходные
$free = ['Суббота', 'Воскресенье'];

$weeks = [
    'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда', 'Четверг',
    'Пятница', 'Суббота', 'Воскресенье'
];

$weeks = array_map(function ($day) use ($time, $free) {
    $length = mb_strlen($day, 'UTF-8');
    $void = str_repeat('&nbsp;', (20 - $length));
    return  in_array($day, $free) 
        ? $day . $void . 'выходной' 
        : $day . $void . $time;
}, $weeks);

$week = date('N');

?>



<select class="top-select">
           <option value="">Время работы офиса</option>
    <?php foreach (range(1, 7) as $day) { ?>
        <?php $selected = ($day == $week ? ' selected' : ''); ?>

        <option class="top-day-options" value="<?= $day ?>"<?= $selected ?>><?= $weeks[--$day] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: [divide option in two column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32413893/5752652)

Comment: @Alex2222 вижу свой код :) Вы так и не нашли решение по его выравниванию? Могу предложить средствами php как временный вариант, если он вам подойдёт, я запишу его в ответ: [смотреть код](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/30611e5a26e01ad84c06444550b6a90bf86b204b)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте добавить атрибут **dir** в Ваш select (Почитать [клац](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/dir)).

Ваш код я слегка упростил, превратив его в статический HTML и уменьшив кол-во пробелов, но суть та же

```html
<select class="top-select" dir='rtl'>
    <option value="">Понедельник&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10:00-17:00</option>
    <option value="">Вторник&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10:00-17:00</option>
    <option value="">Среда&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10:00-17:00</option>
    <option value="">Четверг&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10:00-17:00</option>
    <option value="">Пятница&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10:00-17:00</option>
</select>
```

Еще можно сделать то же самое через CSS:

```css
select {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

```html
<select class="top-select">
    <option value="">Понедельник&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10:00-17:00</option>
    <option value="">Вторник&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10:00-17:00</option>
    <option value="">Среда&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10:00-17:00</option>
    <option value="">Четверг&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10:00-17:00</option>
    <option value="">Пятница&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;10:00-17:00</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Зачем мне статика? будет ли работать тогда скрипт?

Comment: @Alex2222 конечно будет. Просто добавьте атрибут в свою разметку. Я привел минимальный пример, чтобы показать как оно будет работать. Ну т.е. Ваш скрипт в итоге и генерирует подобный HTML. HTML парсится браузером. Браузер видит нужный атрибут (или стиль CSS)  и согласно этому рендерит элементы на странице

Comment: Как я понял, автору надо выравнивание и слева и справа, в этом случае ваш пример работать не будет.

Я использую внешние библиотеки типа jquery-ui для таких целей - они скрывают исходный select и создают свой аналог, реализованный на div - а вот с div уже можно делать и левое и правое выравнивание одновременно + любые стили какие душе угодно

Comment: @Zhihar да понятно, что сторонними либами это сделать можно гораздо симпатичнее. Я отталкивался от того, что можно сделать в текущей ситуации =)

Comment: @Mr. Brightside, да к сожалению в текущей ситуации особенно ничего и не сделать :( html в текущем виде дает мало возможностей для изменения свойств встроенных элементов управления :(

Comment: Ну в итоге у меня выравнивание по правому боку пошло, и выходит такая же кривизна как была только с другой стороны + не работает текущий день недели теперь, это совсем не то что надо